# Need to change boot order in an old MacBook Air running only Elementary OS

Tags: boot, macbook, usb-drive, efi

I want to be able to boot from a USB thumb drive to re-install the Elementary OS.  I've installed Elementary OS​ on my old MacBook Air, and it's only a single boot, no dual-boot or Mac OS​ anymore. So my question is how can I change the boot order?

WHAT I'VE TRIED: 1) When I hold the "Option" key down I get a list of wifi connections to choose from, instead of being able to choose between booting from the USB or the Hard drive.

2) Holding down the "OPT CMD 0 F" doesn't work to open up the EFI to make boot order changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dan! I'm kinda confused by your question. In reading it, it seems as though it's a couple questions lumped together. Could you please edit your question and add some additional clarity? Would love to help! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dan! Give this thread a read: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99289/holding-down-the-option-key-isnt-allowing-me-to-select-windows-os-x-on-startup

Comment: linux_tim, you did what Google couldn't! Thanks.

Comment: It was kind of a shot in the dark as the post noted osX and Win10 but I'm glad it worked out for you! You may want to bookmark the post from my previous comment as you could encounter the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM, THANKS!

Resetting NVRAM

Shut down your Mac.
Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R.
Turn on your Mac.
Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
Release the keys.